# Is there a function in Scheme/Racket that can be used to check if a number lies within a range of numbers

Tags: scheme, range, racket

What is the function in Scheme/Racket that can be used to check if a real number lies within a given range of numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Use `<=`. For instance, to check if `x` is between `0` and `100`, including the endpoints of the range:

```
(<= 0 x 100)
```

Similarly, but excluding the endpoints:

```
(< 0 x 100)
```

Comment: Bright solution! I'm very impressed by the expressive power of Scheme! Range membership can be checked by using simple comparison procedures! Thank you very much!